# Can't append a node to the end of my linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I created a linked list where i can store a string and an int on each node. I can add nodes at the top of the list and i can delete them, but i'm having some troubes appending a node at the end of the list.

My current function `append` will set the node to be at the end of the list, but after i append one node and i try to append another one, i will get `segmentation fault`, as if the program **can't** append a new `last` when there is already another one, i'm currently trying to debug it but i can't find the exact line/s with the error.

```
// self-referential structure                       
struct listNode {                                      
   char *data; // each listNode contains a character
   int num;
   struct listNode *nextPtr; // pointer to next node
}; 


typedef struct listNode ListNode; // synonym for struct listNode
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; // synonym for ListNode*

void append(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value, int valore)
 {  /* 1. allocate node */

    ListNodePtr lastNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)+1);

    ListNode *last = *sPtr; 

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    last->data= malloc(strlen(value));
    strcpy(last->data, value);
    last->num = valore;

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next 
          of it as NULL*/
    lastNode->nextPtr = NULL;

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*sPtr == NULL)
    {
       *sPtr = lastNode;
       return;
    }  

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->nextPtr != NULL)
        last = last->nextPtr;

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->nextPtr = lastNode;

 }

// insert a new value into the list in sorted order
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value, int valore)
{ 
   ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)+1); // create node

   if (newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
      newPtr->data= malloc(strlen(value));
      strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
      newPtr->num = valore;
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...               
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node 
      }                                          
      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
   } 
}
```

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` a (data) pointer. This obfuscates your code, does not save any typing (in fact you have to type even more) and once you use enhanced C features like `const` correctness, it complicates things even more (you will notice once you become a bit skilled in C).

Comment: It's crazy how the same book i used for studying reported a lot of examples of data structures where typedef is used, it should have been more clear

Comment: I did not say not to `typedef` a `struct`. But I agree, thee are many crappy books out there. A lot of them were written for K&R C which did not provide `const` and other qualifiers like `volatile` are often noit used outside bare-metal software. However, as I wrote with more knowledge you should be able to figure out what the problems are about this malpractice - beyond obfuscation. Until then: better be explicit than implicit.

Comment: I'm now looking for more examples and i found a lot of example data structures on geeksforgeeks, those structures are much more clean in fact. The problem is that over my actual model of data structure i built a lot of stuff, so i'd have to re-built everything from scratch again

Comment: You won't learn the language by copy&pating code you found somewhere. Write your own, practice and get comfortable with your debugger. The main part of programming is not typing the code, but design, planning and debugging/testing. I say this after reading your other questions: spoon-feeding is a bad attitude for a programmer.

Comment: Here's one issue: 'newPtr->data= malloc(strlen(value));' - it's one char short, (NUL terminator).

Comment: typedeffing a pointer is not THAT bad, as long as it's obvious, eg 'ListNodePtr' or 'pListNode', (and, of course, used correctly:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a bunch of mistakes here. Not sure what's causing the issue but try to fix this:

Why use synonym  if you're not consistent ?

```
ListNodePtr lastNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)+1);

ListNode *last = *sPtr;
```

Why +1?

```
ListNodePtr lastNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)+1)
```

This:

```
ListNode *last = *sPtr; 

/* 2. put in the data  */
last->data= malloc(strlen(value));
strcpy(last->data, value);
last->num = valore;
```

You overwrite the values of the node that was sent to this method. Probably intended to use lastNode

Now you need +1

```
last->data= malloc(strlen(value));
```

This is what I see for now, dont know if its gonna fix the segmentation fault. How is this error happening? Are you only using this method? or are you doing all kind of manipulation on the data? Maybe the problem is else where . Anyway, I'll have another look and see if I spot anything else.

Comment: I would post the whole program but it's really long. Anyway thank you for your help :)